anaconda can't connect to pycharm
The environment conda packages can be created normally in terminal, but pycharm can't select the virtual environment it creates as the interpreter (it can only select base as the interpreter).I can run the project in the terminal, but there is no way to debug it without pycharm.Even when I clicked ok it didn't respond, and the base environment was still selected.
I reinstalled ananconda and pycahrm multiple times and they're both up to date now!
